# how to show class level validations error on UI using Spring validation

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am validation my beans using hibernate validations (JSR 303).All my validations are working find and i am able to display them successfully on the UI with following code

```
<spring:bind path="lastName">
  <c:if test="${status.error}">
    <li>${status.errorMessage}</li>
</c:if>
</spring:bind>
```

i am facing a problem for one validation which is applicable at class level

```
@EqualAttributes(message = "{validation.checkPwd.equals}", value =
{ "pwd", "checkPwd" })
public class RegisterForm
{
  //bean class
}
```

i am not sure how to show error message with respect to this validation on the UI as i am confused to which field i should bind it

can any one guide me to right path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<spring:bind path="registerForm">
```

Or "command", or whatever name you are using to bind the object.